# SSRS link to another tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple SSRS Report. User is prompted to select parameters, i.e, country name, from date, and to date.  Each row on the redport is a different country the user selected in the parameter dropdown together with a revenue column.  I now require that the country value in each row to be a hyperlink, which, when the user clicks on it, they are navigated to another chart to be on its own page, and the chart retains the parameter values the user entered and shows a revenue trend for that country with the date range being the from and to dates they selected in the parameters. Can this be done within the same SSRS report where the second report (preferably the last page) is just another tablix/matrix with the parameters retained?. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to read about drill thru reports (or subreports) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thank Alan.   I'll read up on this to see if the main report and subreport can be in just one .rdl file instead of two.

Comment: aduguids answer will also work if you want to just hop to different parts of the report but that would mean creating the 'dill down' part for every parameter value up front. You could do this using a list but if you had hundreds of potential parameter combinations it might be slow to render,

Answer (score 0):

Check out bookmarks.

You can add a bookmark to any report item and add a bookmark link to any item that has an Action property, for example, a text box, an image, or a calculated series in a chart.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-bookmark-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3504/sql-server-reporting-services-bookmarks-and-document-maps/

Comment: My bad. I did not indicate requirements clearly. Requirement is to have 2 separate windows; i.e, 2 separate rdl files.  Both currently work fine independently. I am working on creating an Action with a URL to pass the parms to the 2nd report.  So far not successful.  The 2nd report tries to open but nothing happens. This is my url syntax: ="https://mySSRSServer/ReportServer?/MyFolder/My+Report+Name&QVR_Code=" & Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR_List_Dataset") & "&FromDt=" &Parameters!FromDt.Value.  Any guidance on what I am doing wrong in url?